# Upload Image with Django Model Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-file-upload

I'm having difficulty uploading the following model with model form. I can upload fine in the admin but that's not all that useful for a project that limits admin access.

```
#Models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/profile/%Y/%m/')

#views.py
def create_profile(request):
    try: 
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except:
        pass
    form = CreateProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=profile)

    if form.is_valid():
       new = form.save(commit=False)
       new.user = request.user
       new.save()

return render_to_response('profile.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))


#Profile.html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<tr><td>{{ form.as_p }}</td></tr>
<tr><td><button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button></td></tr>
</form>
```

Note: All the other data in the form saves perfectly well, the photo does not upload at all. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass `request.FILES` to your form:

```
form = CreateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
```

Ref: [Handling uploaded files with a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model)

Comment: thanks for your help... so I did that, and my instance disappears from the form... and shows a bunch of validation errors on the form (even though it wasn't submitted).

Answer (score 3):

Form initialization code have to be like this:

```
form = MemberSettingsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=user)
```

Comment: I like this one better because the "or None"

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was a issue with my views.py. You need to set the request.method == POST to make sure you can still have the instance as a part of the form. Works perfectly though.

```
#Views.py

def create_profile(request):
    try: 
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except:
        pass
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
       new = form.save(commit=False)
       new.user = profile.user
       new.save()

else:
     form = CreateProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=profile)


return render_to_response('profile.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

add this before save model instance :

```
 new.profile_pic = request.FILES.get('profile_pic')
```