# Image cannot be displayed after saving the data in Django. The code for it is given below

Tags: python, html, django, image, django-views

Problem Statement:
[In shown image, default profile pic is visible but i need uploaded photo to be displayed here when i upload and saved in the database.I am using django framework.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fahQR.png)

What have I Tried here?

In setting.html file,The below is the HTML code for what is have tried to display image, bio, location. The problem may be at first div image tag. Though the default profile picture is visible but which i have uploaded is not displaying in the page nor able to save in database.

```
<form action="" method ="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-3 lg:p-6 p-4">
<div class="col-span-2">
   <label for="">Profile Image</label>
   <img width = "100" height = "100" src="{{user_profile.profileimg.url}}"/>
   <input type="file" name='image' value = "" placeholder="No file chosen" class="shadow-none bg-gray-100">
</div>
<div class="col-span-2">
   <label for="about">Bio</label>  
   <textarea id="about" name="bio" rows="3"  class="shadow-none bg-gray-100">{{user_profile.bio}}</textarea>
</div> 
<div class="col-span-2">
   <label for=""> Location</label>
   <input type="text" name = "location" value = "{{user_profile.location}}" placeholder="" class="shadow-none bg-gray-100">
</div>
 </div> 
                                
 <div class="bg-gray-10 p-6 pt-0 flex justify-end space-x-3">
 <button class="p-2 px-4 rounded bg-gray-50 text-red-500"> <a href="/"> Cancel</a> </button>
 <button type="submit" class="button bg-blue-700"> Save </button>
 </div>
 </form>
```

In views.py file,the below function is the views file settings page logic for displaying the image, bio, location. If the image is not uploaded, it will be default profile picture. If image is not none then the uploaded image is displayed. But I am not getting what is the mistake here in my code.

```
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def settings(request):
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.FILES.get('image')== None:
            image = user_profile.profileimg
            bio = request.POST['bio']
            location = request.POST['location']

            
        else:
            image = request.FILES.get('image')
            bio = request.POST['bio']
            location = request.POST['location']

        user_profile.profileimg = image
        user_profile.bio = bio
        user_profile.location = location
        user_profile.save()
        return redirect("settings")

    return render(request, 'setting.html', {'user_profile': user_profile})
```

I am expecting to know what the mistake in the code is. Only profileimg cannot be saved in database. the other data is able to save like bio, location.

The below is the model.py file.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    id_user = models.IntegerField()
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    profileimg = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_images', default= 'blank-profile-picture.png')
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

The below is the media folder in settings.py file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
]
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Photo is not displaying.
[image: Photo is not displaying.]

Comment: where the uploaded img is saving. Means, media folder or static folder

Comment: It should be saved in media folder. But It is not saving and not displaying.

Comment: show me models.py

Comment: Show the form you are using to upload the image.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as screenshots of text. Your urlpatterns are ruined by `= [] +` - this is a complete overwrite by empty list.

Comment: Not related to image handling but this `if request.FILES.get('image') != None:` should be stated as `else:`. And lines not related to image handling do not need to be copy-pasted in each flow - just move them out of if-else like you did to the final redirect. `Profile.objects.get` should be `...get_object_or_404`. Instead of `image = user_profile.profileimg ... user_profile.profileimg = image` just don't do anything to the profileimg field if image is not provided.

Comment: Please show the whole form code with submit button and so on. Also take a look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148437/upload-image-with-django-model-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I found solution

```
<form action="" method ="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
```

This enctype is missing in setting.html file. This works correctly and image displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try this way:

```
<img width = "100" height = "100" src="/media/{{user_profile.profileimg}}"/>
```

And now that image will display

Note: If your uploaded image is saving in media folder then above code will work.

According to your model field profileimg, you should add forward slash to upload_to:

It must be like below:

```
upload_to='profile_images/'
```

And ensure that you have added this in your main urls:

```
urlpatterns = [

]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Its not saving in media folder. It is the problem here.

Comment: please provide models.py and settings.py file

Comment: Modified the above question and provided models.py file and settings.py file code.

Comment: updated my answer try that

Comment: I tried your answer, but it is not working. The default pic is only visible. The uploaded image is not saved in folder and not displaying.

Comment: have you added this setting in main urls +static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: Yes used as below,                                                                                                urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
]


urlpatterns = urlpatterns+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: It must look like only this urlpatterns = 
[ ]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: look closely, how i added

Comment: No, Its not working and giving new error., It shows page not found 404 error.

Comment: which error show me

Comment: check the error screenshot in question ending.

Comment: please share main urls not app urls. i want to see how you added

Comment: Its main url only, not app url. I have checked it. The code looks like this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFZFR.png

Comment: I knew it you made mistake here

Comment: you should not create seperate urlpatterns for that setting

Comment: you should add that setting in existing urlpatterns

Comment: you should add this after ending square brackets like this ]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) in existing urlpatterns

Comment: once again, `"/media/{{user_profile.profileimg}}"` is a misleading advice.

Comment: @IvanStarostin means this will not work

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fetch the image in the wrong way.

Instead you can use this

```
src="/media/{{user_profile.profileimg}}"
```

If it doesn't work try removing "/" before media.

Please reply to this message if the issue still persist.

Comment: The problem is still existing after trying this solution.

Comment: Building hardcoded url instead of using django features for storing and accessing media files is a misleading advice. In lucky scenario it will just build the same URL as the django-way approach will. Still - hardcoded instead of generated with respect to actual configuration. Leading slash has nothing to do with media or static files config and is a guess which lacks explanation. The only change to behavior: the url will become relative instead of  being absolute which is a problem, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Holy Shit.
How could I miss it.

My friend problem is with view.

Add this thing to your function:

```
    if request.method == "POST" and "image" in request.FILES:
```

And while requesting for the image place the image only in the variable in list as given below.

```
        image= request.FILES['image']
```

I hope this should resolve. Please revert back if the issue still persist.

Comment: Please update your original answer instead of posting multiple partial answers. Also your suggestion does not seem to be any different to the existing code. OP does have both conditions already.